# Golang large response unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: http, go, unmarshalling

I'm sending a request to a server and trying to unmarshall HTTP Response. It's weird, but some of the responses return 200 and do not give an unmarshall error, while some of them return 200 and give an unmarshall error.

My client code looks like:

```
func SendRequest(requestModel *model.Request) (*model.Response, error) {
    responseModel := &dspModel.Response{}
    byteData, err := json.Marshal(requestModel)
    if err != nil {
        zap.S().Errorf("Error marshalling request. Err: %v", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    url := "xx"
    request, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, url, bytes.NewBuffer(byteData))
    request.Close = true
    client := &http.Client{}

    response, err := client.Do(request)
    if err, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && err.Timeout() {
        zap.S().Error("Response timeout exceed")
        return nil, errors.New("Response timeout exceed")
    }
    if err != nil || response == nil {
        errorMessage := "not respond"
        zap.S().Error(errorMessage)
        return nil, errors.New(errorMessage)
    }

    defer response.Body.Close()
    if response.StatusCode == http.StatusOK {
        err = json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&responseModel)
        if err != nil {
            // Error occurred here!
            errorMessage := "Request response decode error"
            zap.S().Errorf("%v, Err: %v", errorMessage, err)
            return nil, errors.New(errorMessage)
        }
        return response, nil
    } else if response.StatusCode == http.StatusNoContent {
        return nil, nil
    } else {
        bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
        errorMessage := "not respond"
        zap.S().Errorf("%v, StatusCode %v, Response: %v Request: %v", errorMessage, 
response.StatusCode, string(bodyBytes), string(byteData))
        return nil, errors.New(errorMessage)
    }
}
```

I suspect response cause it's too long and has different characters.
Response looks like:

```
{"tax":{"ver":"1.0"},"cur":"EUR","rack":[{"tur":[{"zar":2.599886212,"domain":["test.com"],"ney":"https://censored.com/nimp?fuid=&ic=EWRMh-.UTPdNvWB-JYa58c85N0fEPgXunKp3wwyPadp7jwqHgZbz4dG0A51OVO-2Gs0znYmLcPIH0ThEmpsYl8wKofo9ytJ2A3uWr9Kn-dNxeh.k8lIml9kavPk1.dk7f.46xKX7IVpf3.yU-Yx1KetQl3Q9f-iePn7B86yjVgMxkTNfhZAg0pP0kKZaJMd2orLXoV4xPXmwTdfJbWJU5bGAUROJT-Yd7yTHoVveuvOBClHzM4cgHFmGxzox6cCJ2gZB.7fqKkPzECXwdpobmO0RWxdu224-FADd.oM4DghIEpdZJe.FjEq0stQnJBT.puw0JamHgT15NdSQN7voBJ8UqGCDOu1qSLece6Iy.PN392xGWhxs0URbrWhSEgkhCr.R4ol9kjrMqK78shw2gHBJjEzKeBeo6lBzU8YfoKDM7oPlj5SwmL6sV2i2UaWJbEtreRt3oABDPab--AevfJW2rQ0-2iyt-rJSPjDHHoOQEFoh0G7cPm8SIZxk17ojWkFdM7CXlmuSN0paqMhp-4gWlfgvNq8a65I8GfY8cwVrW5KzRszHLhWYareVM3MNpejdcVH2kinEnYzBVyW0e8oN06LC2icG8FRlhOC2N8wni66liT73RvKyFFT1zW7SAoqtgn9KXY6m.EaZzSx3aapIMGpG9-S8q6mwAuwZId37ri4GTiLXp6OMABsLwT3sMUOm.Kktp.uYP1z2be2DFM6zKKPL7YJopAvdfS7TdhMfHD6Dfcv-EvK6Q0lNylaFIjegbNjPEPPXzLPdf8iwLK-dqfSe127TZcj5xJUFwo45IgFl0i0puKRIzsAtM2W3zM-TNc2HEc0nIllK.aoKZ0tF9iSekzjcNnMAvhcAKBqq6DY.qIBUs5yOoxqW4m-ga9drHp09VXIkn7st7J4IUlrMZFuVHnnzbeqD61AKKFiaRCqPee6Y88DqhsdNt7SzdA-xq9SKnJW67zsZTD0T9OoRl3.nLaSwoQ==&t=adi&prc=${censored}","tax":{"name":"test"},"hy":3020,"ny":2530,"arz":"<script type=\"text/javascript\">var _CDurl='';(function(){_CDurl=encodeURIComponent(document.URL);})();document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://censored/at?bad=&gad=&ic=EWRMh-.UTPdNvWB-JYa58c85N0fEPgXunKp3wwyPadp7jwqHgZbz4dG0A51OVO-2Gs0znYmLcPIH0ThEmpsYl8wKofo9ytJ2A3uWr9Kn-dNxeh.k8lIml9kavPk1.dk7f.46xKX7IVpf3.yU-Yx1KetQl3Q9f-iePn7B86yjVgMxkTNfhZAg0pP0kKZaJMd2orLXoV4xPXmwTdfJbWJU5bGAUROJT-Yd7yTHoVveuvOBClHzM4cgHFmGxzox6cCJ2gZB.7fqKkPzECXwdpobmO0RWxdu224-FADd.oM4DghIEpdZJe.FjEq0stQnJBT.puw0JamHgT15NdSQN7voBJ8UqGCDOu1qSLece6Iy.PN392xGWhxs0URbrWhSEgkhCr.R4ol9kjrMqK78shw2gHBJjEzKeBeo6lBzU8YfoKDM7oPlj5SwmL6sV2i2UaWJbEtreRt3oABDPab--AevfJW2rQ0-2iyt-rJSPjDHHoOQEFoh0G7cPm8SIZxk17ojWkFdM7CXlmuSN0paqMhp-4gWlfgvNq8a65I8GfY8cwVrW5KzRszHLhWYareVM3MNpejdcVH2kinEnYzBVyW0e8oN06LC2icG8FRlhOC2N8wni66liT73RvKyFFT1zW7SAoqtgn9KXY6m.EaZzSx3aapIMGpG9-S8q6mwAuwZId37ri4GTiLXp6OMABsLwT3sMUOm.Kktp.uYP1z2be2DFM6zKKPL7YJopAvdfS7TdhMfHD6Dfcv-EvK6Q0lNylaFIjegbNjPEPPXzLPdf8iwLK-dqfSe127TZcj5xJUFwo45IgFl0i0puKRIzsAtM2W3zM-TNc2HEc0nIllK.aoKZ0tF9iSekzjcNnMAvhcAKBqq6DY.qIBUs5yOoxqW4m-ga9drHp09VXIkn7st7J4IUlrMZFuVHnnzbeqD61AKKFiaRCqPee6Y88DqhsdNt7SzdA-xq9SKnJW67zsZTD0T9OoRl3.nLaSwoQ==&t=adj&prc=${censored}&tat='+_CDurl+'\"></scr' + 'ipt>');</script>"}],"tark":"1"}],"gno":"55f03d71-f021-49e0-a1a5-cae4315b3561"}
```

When I debug the error, I noticed that after half of the response is not visible.
Error statement:

```
"msg":"Request response decode error, Response: {\"tax\":{\"ver\":\"1.0\"},\"cur\":\"EUR\",\"rac\":[{\"btyrd\":[{\"zar\":2.599886212,\"domain\":[\"test.com\"],\"ney\":\"https://censored/nimp?fuid=&ic=EWRMh-.UTPdNvWB-JYa58c85N0fEPgXunKp3wwyPadp7jwqHgZbz4dG0A51OVO-2Gs0znYmLcPIH0ThEmpsYl8wKofo9ytJ2A3uWr9Kn-dNxeh.k8lIml9kavPk1.dk7f.46xKX7IVpf3.yU-Yx1KetQl3Q9f-iePn7B86yjVgMxkTNfhZAg0pP0kKZaJMd2orLXoV4xPXmwTdfJbWJU5bGAUROJT-Yd7yTHoVveuvOBClHzM4cgHFmGxzox6cCJ2gZB.7fqKkPzECXwdpobmO0RWxdu224-FADd.oM4DghIEpdZJe.FjEq0stQnJBT.puw0JamHgT15NdSQN7voBJ8UqGCDOu1q, Err: unexpected end of JSON input"
```

Response Model:

```
type Response struct {
    Tax  Tax    `json:"tax"`
    Cur  string `json:"cur"`
    Rack []Rack `json:"rack"`
    Gno  string `json:"gno"`
}
type Tax struct {
    Ver string `json:"ver"`
}
type TaxOfTur struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
type Tur struct {
    Zar    float64  `json:"zar"`
    Domain []string `json:"domain"`
    Ney    string   `json:"ney"`
    Tax    TaxOfTur `json:"tax"`
    Hy     int      `json:"hy"`
    Ny     int      `json:"ny"`
    Arz    string   `json:"arz"`
}
type Rack struct {
    Tur  []Tur  `json:"tur"`
    Tark string `json:"tark"`
}
```

Probably unrelated but requests are going concurrent and my test case is based on only one concurrent request. So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: better share `responseModel` structure also.. for more understanding..

Comment: can it be some char in the reponse that triggers that behavior?

Comment: I am not sure that this has to do with the string being too long, as the JSON you included in this post is actually perfectly valid. Instead, I think it might have to do with the fact that you are setting `request.Close = true`. How are you calling this concurrently? Could you show us a bit?

Comment: Are you able to measure how long it takes from the start of the request to the moment when you receive an error from the JSON decoder? Maybe you encounter some network timeouts because of slow server/network.

Comment: log out the `content length` header value and `len(response.Body)`, if  `len(response.Body)` < `content length` then some read errors had happen, but then you should get that into the error returned by the `json.decoder`. If they match, then the remote sends corrupted responses.  I could not manage to emit the same error using the json decoder ( https://play.golang.org/p/ErXdPfPFWn5 ) maybe using the right input from your use case you could make that happen. The goal was to check if these error embeds underlying transfer error, if any. I think it does, but that needs further investigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to implement your code at my end, and it's giving the expected output. The code I tried is given below.

Note: This is not a solution to the exact problem, since I was not able to reproduce the same.

```golang
// Response struct definition here...
// ..

// The trouble making JSON.
const msg = `{"tax":{"ver":"1.0"},"cur":"EUR","rack":[{"tur":[{"zar":2.599886212,"domain":["test.com"],"ney":"https://censored.com/nimp?fuid=&ic=EWRMh-.UTPdNvWB-JYa58c85N0fEPgXunKp3wwyPadp7jwqHgZbz4dG0A51OVO-2Gs0znYmLcPIH0ThEmpsYl8wKofo9ytJ2A3uWr9Kn-dNxeh.k8lIml9kavPk1.dk7f.46xKX7IVpf3.yU-Yx1KetQl3Q9f-iePn7B86yjVgMxkTNfhZAg0pP0kKZaJMd2orLXoV4xPXmwTdfJbWJU5bGAUROJT-Yd7yTHoVveuvOBClHzM4cgHFmGxzox6cCJ2gZB.7fqKkPzECXwdpobmO0RWxdu224-FADd.oM4DghIEpdZJe.FjEq0stQnJBT.puw0JamHgT15NdSQN7voBJ8UqGCDOu1qSLece6Iy.PN392xGWhxs0URbrWhSEgkhCr.R4ol9kjrMqK78shw2gHBJjEzKeBeo6lBzU8YfoKDM7oPlj5SwmL6sV2i2UaWJbEtreRt3oABDPab--AevfJW2rQ0-2iyt-rJSPjDHHoOQEFoh0G7cPm8SIZxk17ojWkFdM7CXlmuSN0paqMhp-4gWlfgvNq8a65I8GfY8cwVrW5KzRszHLhWYareVM3MNpejdcVH2kinEnYzBVyW0e8oN06LC2icG8FRlhOC2N8wni66liT73RvKyFFT1zW7SAoqtgn9KXY6m.EaZzSx3aapIMGpG9-S8q6mwAuwZId37ri4GTiLXp6OMABsLwT3sMUOm.Kktp.uYP1z2be2DFM6zKKPL7YJopAvdfS7TdhMfHD6Dfcv-EvK6Q0lNylaFIjegbNjPEPPXzLPdf8iwLK-dqfSe127TZcj5xJUFwo45IgFl0i0puKRIzsAtM2W3zM-TNc2HEc0nIllK.aoKZ0tF9iSekzjcNnMAvhcAKBqq6DY.qIBUs5yOoxqW4m-ga9drHp09VXIkn7st7J4IUlrMZFuVHnnzbeqD61AKKFiaRCqPee6Y88DqhsdNt7SzdA-xq9SKnJW67zsZTD0T9OoRl3.nLaSwoQ==&t=adi&prc=${censored}","tax":{"name":"test"},"hy":3020,"ny":2530,"arz":"<script type=\"text/javascript\">var _CDurl='';(function(){_CDurl=encodeURIComponent(document.URL);})();document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://censored/at?bad=&gad=&ic=EWRMh-.UTPdNvWB-JYa58c85N0fEPgXunKp3wwyPadp7jwqHgZbz4dG0A51OVO-2Gs0znYmLcPIH0ThEmpsYl8wKofo9ytJ2A3uWr9Kn-dNxeh.k8lIml9kavPk1.dk7f.46xKX7IVpf3.yU-Yx1KetQl3Q9f-iePn7B86yjVgMxkTNfhZAg0pP0kKZaJMd2orLXoV4xPXmwTdfJbWJU5bGAUROJT-Yd7yTHoVveuvOBClHzM4cgHFmGxzox6cCJ2gZB.7fqKkPzECXwdpobmO0RWxdu224-FADd.oM4DghIEpdZJe.FjEq0stQnJBT.puw0JamHgT15NdSQN7voBJ8UqGCDOu1qSLece6Iy.PN392xGWhxs0URbrWhSEgkhCr.R4ol9kjrMqK78shw2gHBJjEzKeBeo6lBzU8YfoKDM7oPlj5SwmL6sV2i2UaWJbEtreRt3oABDPab--AevfJW2rQ0-2iyt-rJSPjDHHoOQEFoh0G7cPm8SIZxk17ojWkFdM7CXlmuSN0paqMhp-4gWlfgvNq8a65I8GfY8cwVrW5KzRszHLhWYareVM3MNpejdcVH2kinEnYzBVyW0e8oN06LC2icG8FRlhOC2N8wni66liT73RvKyFFT1zW7SAoqtgn9KXY6m.EaZzSx3aapIMGpG9-S8q6mwAuwZId37ri4GTiLXp6OMABsLwT3sMUOm.Kktp.uYP1z2be2DFM6zKKPL7YJopAvdfS7TdhMfHD6Dfcv-EvK6Q0lNylaFIjegbNjPEPPXzLPdf8iwLK-dqfSe127TZcj5xJUFwo45IgFl0i0puKRIzsAtM2W3zM-TNc2HEc0nIllK.aoKZ0tF9iSekzjcNnMAvhcAKBqq6DY.qIBUs5yOoxqW4m-ga9drHp09VXIkn7st7J4IUlrMZFuVHnnzbeqD61AKKFiaRCqPee6Y88DqhsdNt7SzdA-xq9SKnJW67zsZTD0T9OoRl3.nLaSwoQ==&t=adj&prc=${censored}&tat='+_CDurl+'\"></scr' + 'ipt>');</script>"}],"tark":"1"}],"gno":"55f03d71-f021-49e0-a1a5-cae4315b3561"}`

func SendRequest() (*Response, error) { 
    url := "http://localhost:8080/foo" // dummy server
    request, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, url, nil)
    request.Close = true
    client := &http.Client{}

    response, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    resBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    responseModel := &Response{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(resBody, &responseModel)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return responseModel, nil
}

func StartDummyServer() {
    handler := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprint(w, msg)
    }
    http.HandleFunc("/foo", handler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

func main() {
    // a dummy server is created to send the response
    go StartDummyServer()
    time.Sleep(time.Second)

    resp, err := SendRequest()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(prettyPrint(resp))

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)
}


func prettyPrint(i interface{}) string {
    s, _ := json.MarshalIndent(i, "", " ")
    return string(s)
}
```

Here is the console output:

```json
{
 "tax": {
  "ver": "1.0"
 },
 "cur": "EUR",
 "rack": [
  {
   "tur": [
    {
     "zar": 2.599886212,
     "domain": [
      "test.com"
     ],
     "ney": "https://censored.com/nimp?fuid=\u0026ic=EWRMh-.UTPdNvWB-JYa58c85N0fEPgXunKp3wwyPadp7jwqHgZbz4dG0A51OVO-2Gs0znYmLcPIH0ThEmpsYl8wKofo9ytJ2A3uWr9Kn-dNxeh.k8lIml9kavPk1.dk7f.46xKX7IVpf3.yU-Yx1KetQl3Q9f-iePn7B86yjVgMxkTNfhZAg0pP0kKZaJMd2orLXoV4xPXmwTdfJbWJU5bGAUROJT-Yd7yTHoVveuvOBClHzM4cgHFmGxzox6cCJ2gZB.7fqKkPzECXwdpobmO0RWxdu224-FADd.oM4DghIEpdZJe.FjEq0stQnJBT.puw0JamHgT15NdSQN7voBJ8UqGCDOu1qSLece6Iy.PN392xGWhxs0URbrWhSEgkhCr.R4ol9kjrMqK78shw2gHBJjEzKeBeo6lBzU8YfoKDM7oPlj5SwmL6sV2i2UaWJbEtreRt3oABDPab--AevfJW2rQ0-2iyt-rJSPjDHHoOQEFoh0G7cPm8SIZxk17ojWkFdM7CXlmuSN0paqMhp-4gWlfgvNq8a65I8GfY8cwVrW5KzRszHLhWYareVM3MNpejdcVH2kinEnYzBVyW0e8oN06LC2icG8FRlhOC2N8wni66liT73RvKyFFT1zW7SAoqtgn9KXY6m.EaZzSx3aapIMGpG9-S8q6mwAuwZId37ri4GTiLXp6OMABsLwT3sMUOm.Kktp.uYP1z2be2DFM6zKKPL7YJopAvdfS7TdhMfHD6Dfcv-EvK6Q0lNylaFIjegbNjPEPPXzLPdf8iwLK-dqfSe127TZcj5xJUFwo45IgFl0i0puKRIzsAtM2W3zM-TNc2HEc0nIllK.aoKZ0tF9iSekzjcNnMAvhcAKBqq6DY.qIBUs5yOoxqW4m-ga9drHp09VXIkn7st7J4IUlrMZFuVHnnzbeqD61AKKFiaRCqPee6Y88DqhsdNt7SzdA-xq9SKnJW67zsZTD0T9OoRl3.nLaSwoQ==\u0026t=adi\u0026prc=${censored}",
     "tax": {
      "name": "test"
     },
     "hy": 3020,
     "ny": 2530,
     "arz": "\u003cscript type=\"text/javascript\"\u003evar _CDurl='';(function(){_CDurl=encodeURIComponent(document.URL);})();document.write('\u003cscr' + 'ipt type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://censored/at?bad=\u0026gad=\u0026ic=EWRMh-.UTPdNvWB-JYa58c85N0fEPgXunKp3wwyPadp7jwqHgZbz4dG0A51OVO-2Gs0znYmLcPIH0ThEmpsYl8wKofo9ytJ2A3uWr9Kn-dNxeh.k8lIml9kavPk1.dk7f.46xKX7IVpf3.yU-Yx1KetQl3Q9f-iePn7B86yjVgMxkTNfhZAg0pP0kKZaJMd2orLXoV4xPXmwTdfJbWJU5bGAUROJT-Yd7yTHoVveuvOBClHzM4cgHFmGxzox6cCJ2gZB.7fqKkPzECXwdpobmO0RWxdu224-FADd.oM4DghIEpdZJe.FjEq0stQnJBT.puw0JamHgT15NdSQN7voBJ8UqGCDOu1qSLece6Iy.PN392xGWhxs0URbrWhSEgkhCr.R4ol9kjrMqK78shw2gHBJjEzKeBeo6lBzU8YfoKDM7oPlj5SwmL6sV2i2UaWJbEtreRt3oABDPab--AevfJW2rQ0-2iyt-rJSPjDHHoOQEFoh0G7cPm8SIZxk17ojWkFdM7CXlmuSN0paqMhp-4gWlfgvNq8a65I8GfY8cwVrW5KzRszHLhWYareVM3MNpejdcVH2kinEnYzBVyW0e8oN06LC2icG8FRlhOC2N8wni66liT73RvKyFFT1zW7SAoqtgn9KXY6m.EaZzSx3aapIMGpG9-S8q6mwAuwZId37ri4GTiLXp6OMABsLwT3sMUOm.Kktp.uYP1z2be2DFM6zKKPL7YJopAvdfS7TdhMfHD6Dfcv-EvK6Q0lNylaFIjegbNjPEPPXzLPdf8iwLK-dqfSe127TZcj5xJUFwo45IgFl0i0puKRIzsAtM2W3zM-TNc2HEc0nIllK.aoKZ0tF9iSekzjcNnMAvhcAKBqq6DY.qIBUs5yOoxqW4m-ga9drHp09VXIkn7st7J4IUlrMZFuVHnnzbeqD61AKKFiaRCqPee6Y88DqhsdNt7SzdA-xq9SKnJW67zsZTD0T9OoRl3.nLaSwoQ==\u0026t=adj\u0026prc=${censored}\u0026tat='+_CDurl+'\"\u003e\u003c/scr' + 'ipt\u003e');\u003c/script\u003e"
    }
   ],
   "tark": "1"
  }
 ],
 "gno": "55f03d71-f021-49e0-a1a5-cae4315b3561"
}
```

---

Also, I used the same code you are using, after commenting off the request body part(since I don't have it) and changing the function signature(of `SendRequest`) a bit as given below. All others are as same as the code given above.

```golang
func SendRequest() (*Response, error) {
    responseModel := &Response{}
    // Commented off since the response body is not with me..
    // byteData, err := json.Marshal(requestModel)
    // if err != nil {
    //      zap.S().Errorf("Error marshalling request. Err: %v", err)
    //      return nil, err
    // }

    url := "http://localhost:8080/foo"
    request, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, url /*bytes.NewBuffer(byteData)*/, nil)
    request.Close = true
    client := &http.Client{}

    response, err := client.Do(request)
    if err, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && err.Timeout() {
        log.Fatal("Response timeout exceed")
        return nil, errors.New("Response timeout exceed")
    }
    if err != nil || response == nil {
        errorMessage := "not respond"
        log.Fatal(errorMessage)
        return nil, errors.New(errorMessage)
    }

    defer response.Body.Close()
    if response.StatusCode == http.StatusOK {
        err = json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&responseModel)
        if err != nil {
            errorMessage := "Request response decode error"
            log.Printf("%v, Err: %v", errorMessage, err)
            return nil, errors.New(errorMessage)
        }
        return responseModel, nil
    } else {
        bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
        errorMessage := "not respond"
        log.Printf("%v, StatusCode %v, Response: %v\n", errorMessage, response.StatusCode, string(bodyBytes))
        return nil, errors.New(errorMessage)
    }
}
```

With this as well, I am able to Unmarshal the response successfully.

---

So, in my opinion, the incoming response is not correct(may be). Try printing the incoming data and verify.

```golang
resBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
fmt.Printf("%s", resBody) //
```

Comment: I guess you're right because I don't have problems anymore. I think there is a problem with the server.